# When are these "Bonus" periods for Light Capturing and Mahatma Awakening?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

On ffxiv.consolegameswiki for the [Nexus Relic Weapon](https://ffxiv.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/Nexus_Zodiac_Weapons/Quest#Light_Events) and [Zodiac Zeta](https://ffxiv.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/Zodiac_Zeta_Weapons/Quest#Light_Events), under Light Levels they both make mention of a "bonus period

for Nexus:

> *Some dungeons only give Bright light, such as Copperbell Mines (Hard). Both Sastasha (easiest) and Aurum Vale (quickest) give Brilliant (non-bonus).

for Zodiac Zeta

> Soloing 1x Sastasha or Aurum Vale is enough to fully awaken a Mahatma if you are in a 2-hour bonus window for it. For high level jobs running The Aurum Vale will be quicker than Sastasha.

While I was working on The Veil of Wiyu running Aurum Vale on a monday night AEST (~10-11PM) i was noticing that i was getting Blinding Light which halved the amount of work i needed to do. since 1 run of Aurum Vale is enough to awaken a Mahatma i would like to plan run the Zodiac Zeta stage then along with any other weapon i collect in the future

however i don't know exactly when these "2-hour bonus window"s occur and currently i have no way to test until i finish getting all the item to progress to the Zodiac stage (and also self RP wise, i promised The Veil of Wiyu and Omnilex that one would not become a Zodiac without the other and Omnilex isn't even on Zenith yet so would be some time because i can test with Omnilex Novus)

So when are these "Bonus" periods for Light Capturing and Mahatma Awakening?

Answer (score 1):

The duties having light bonus aren't shown anywhere in the game, and are seemingly random (I never found accurate data about rotations). The only way to know is from doing duties and checking yourself.

Back in ARR, there used to be websites tracking the windows, but since then, with the ability to run dungeons unsynced, making them way faster, there isn't such website anymore.

The tip is to do a run of Sastasha and Aurum Vale (maybe Tam-Tara too), and check if one of them has the light bonus and stick to it. Ifrit NM is also often recommended as it takes 3 seconds (plus loading time) to die when unsynced.

Note that you need to have the weapon equipped when killing the last boss of the dungeon to get the light, which stops you from farming 2 weapons light at once.